# Can't push to a repo after rebase

Tags: git, github

I'm having some trouble with git `rebase`. I have forked a public repository. In my fork I have a `master` branch and a `feature` branch. I have developed and committed code in `feature` and now I create a pull request directly into the upstream repository.

But, by the time I am ready to create a pr, the upstream master has already merged new commits. So I need to update my local repo before the pr can go through. To do this I `checkout` into master and run `gh repo sync origin my-github/the-repo`. I then `git pull`. After I `checkout` to `feature` and run `rebase master`. This works smoothly, no problems here. The problem is when I try to push changes to the remote `feature`. I get the following error:

```
 ! [rejected]            squares-of-id -> squares-of-id (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my-github/the-repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Can someone help explain why my local ends up behind my remote? And hopeful provide a fix?

Comment: Was that unexpected? You _rewrote history_ by rebasing, so your local copy no longer matches the remote. Please research the error message, there are plenty of resources on SO and elsewhere about this already.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess that does make sense. This was just how I was told to go about things, so I didn't think it would cause problems like this. What is the better way to integrate changes? (also, I thought it wouldn't rewrite changes that I made on my local repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rebasing you rewrite the history and as a result your local history does not match with the upstream's history anymore. Public branches should never be rewritten as that might cause lots of problems downstream.

However, if this is your personal branch it is fine and you can force the server to accept your commits/history by invoking `git push --force-with-lease`